# RegEx Performance Issue

Tags: c#, .net, regex

We are having problem with the following regular expression:

```
(.*?)\|\*\|([0-9]+)\*\|\*(.*?)
```

It should match things like: `|*25 *|`

We are using .Net Framework 4 RegEx Class the code is the following:

```
string expression = "(.*?)" + 
       Regex.Escape(Constants.FIELD_START_DELIMITER_BACK_END) + 
       "([0-9]+)" + 
       Regex.Escape(Constants.FIELD_END_DELIMITER_BACK_END) + 
       "(.*?)";
Regex r = new Regex(expression);
r.Matches(contentText)
```

It is taking too long (like 60 seconds) with a 40.000 character text.

But with a text of 180.000 the speed its very acceptable (3 sec or less)

The only difference between texts its that the first text(the one which is slow) it is all contained in a single line, with no line breaks. Can this be an issue? That is affecting the performance?

Thanks

Comment: How is performance with RegexOptions.Compiled?

Comment: Have try with compiled option but have seen not significant improvement.

Comment: @AustinSalonen Complied will only help you if you create the instance of the Regex outside of the main code. If you just tacked on Compiled to the example code it would potentially slow it down even more.

Comment: Have you run a profiler on it and you are sure that the Regex code is causing the problem? You can run the one built in to Visual Studio, and let us know what % of the time is the code spending in this section. (you can filter the results so it only uses the time it actually was parsing to calculate the %). Also give us a little more code so we can see what you are doing with the result from `r.Matches`

Comment: Ok got your point, but why would that affect performance so much? My main issue here is that the text I testing its all contained in a single line. If I put line breaks to that text the Matching its performed much faster.

Comment: I have not run a Profiler but debuggin the code I can see specifically that the problem is when the line RegEx.IsMatch(contentText) it takes more than 40 seconds to execute that line.

Comment: Why are you capturing (.*?) at the start and end? Also if you gave us more real code showing exactly how you set up and check that the Regex has a match (You never use `IsMatch` in your example code)

Comment: My suspicion is that the lookahead is eating you up.  (.*?) means the same as (.*).  And, in fact, you shouldn't need it at all.  I believe that, in this context, you can just write string expression = Regex.Escape(Constants.FIELD_START_DELIMITER_BACK_END) + "([0-9]+)" + Regex.Escape(Constants.FIELD_END_DELIMITER_BACK_END);

Comment: @David - That's a lazy quantifier, not a lookahead. You are right, however, it really isn't needed. I'll add this comment to my answer, if you don't mind, but feel free to add a complete answer with code that demonstrates it, it is a much better option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@David Gorsline's solution (from the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146158/regex-performance-issue#comment13010531_10146158)) is correct:

```
string expression =
    Regex.Escape(Constants.FIELD_START_DELIMITER_BACK_END) + 
    "([0-9]+)" + 
    Regex.Escape(Constants.FIELD_END_DELIMITER_BACK_END);
```

Specifically, it's the `(.*?)` at the beginning that's doing you in.  What that does is take over doing what the regex engine should be doing itself--scan for the next place where the regex can match--and doing it much, much less efficiently.  At each position, the `(.*?)` effectively performs a lookahead to determine whether the next part of the regex can match, and only if that fails does it go ahead and consume the next character.

But even if you used something more efficient, like `[^|]*`, you would still be slowing it down.  Leave that part off, though, and the regex engine can instead scan for the first constant portion of the regex, probably using an algorithm like Boyer-Moore or Knuth-Morris-Pratt.  So don't worry about what's *around* the bits you want to match; just tell the regex engine what you're looking for and get out of its way.

On the other hand, the *trailing* `(.*?)` has virtually no effect, because it never really does anything.  The `?` turns the `.*` reluctant, so what does it take to make it go ahead and consume the next character?  It will only do so if there's something following it in the regex that *forces* it to.  For example, `foo.*?bar` consumes everything from the next "foo" to the next "bar" after that, but `foo.*?` stops as soon as it's consumed "foo".  It *never* makes sense to have a reluctant quantifier as the last thing in a regex.

Answer (score 2):

You've answered your question: the problem is that `.` fails to match new-lines (it doesn't by default), which results in many failed attempts - almost one for every position on your 40000 character string.
On the long but single lined file, the engine can match the pattern in a **single pass** over the file (assuming a successful match exists - if it doesn't, I suspect it will take a long time to fail...).
On the shorter file, with many lines, the engine tries to match from the first character. It matches `.*?` until the end of the first line (this is a lazy match, so a lot more is happening, but lets ignore that), and fails. Now, it stats again from the **second character**, not the second line! This results in n² complexity even before matching the number.

A simple solution is to make `.` match newlines:

```
Regex r = new Regex(expression, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

You can also make sure to match from start to end using the absolute start and end anchors, `\A` and `\z`:

```
string expression = "\\A(.*?)" + 
   Regex.Escape(Constants.FIELD_START_DELIMITER_BACK_END) + 
   "([0-9]+)" + 
   Regex.Escape(Constants.FIELD_END_DELIMITER_BACK_END) + 
   "(.*?)\\z";
```

Another note:
As David suggests in the comments, `\|\*\|([0-9]+)\*\|\*` should work well enough. Even if you need to "capture" all text before and after the match, you can easily get it using the position of the match.

Comment: Actually setting the option to Singleline didnt helped. But your explanation about why is the performance issue I agree.
Regarding the final solution. David was right and my regular expression had unnecesaries:(.?) so I removed them and the performance issue disappeared totally

Comment: @user - that is interesting... is it possible the pattern didn't match for that file?